# sql query to get the most recent piece of data for a given set of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table that represents a history for 'elements' in my table. An element is determined by a grouping of 2 columns

The historic data has actions that occurred like "saved" or "deleted" which can happen many times for any element. These are mutually exclusive so when I look at the current state, care about the most recent action.

I want to count the number of "saved" events for an element. This needs to be the count of the most recent historic event that is a "saved" for every element. Is there one SQL query that does this well? I have 2 that I want to condense.

**Table columns**:
    time (timestamp),
    user_id (int),
    file_name (string), 
    action_type (string)

The `user_id` + `file_name` combo determines an 'element' I care about but this combo is not unique in the table

What I want: Get the count of the file "index.html" for all users who most recently "saved" it as their action

Comment: please paste db structure

Comment: your question can be more meaningful if you provide a table structure, sample records and your desired result `:)`

Comment: it's in postgres (just updated that)

Comment: Do you have a `datestamp` column that can be used to determine when the event took place?  Otherwise, what does "*most recent*" actually mean?

Comment: yes! i forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like below.  It first of all filters out all the SAVED records for index.html.  Then it discards any of those records where there exists a new record for the same user and file.

So if user1 saved the file at 09:00 and at 12:00, only the 12:00 record would count.

```
select count(*) from tableName t
where t.action_type = 'SAVED'
and t.filename = 'index.html'
and not exists 
   (select * from tableName t2
    where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.filename = t.filename
    and t2.time > t.time
    and t2.action_type = 'SAVED')
```

If you want it so that a more recent delete record stops save being counted, remove the `and t2.action_type = 'SAVED'` bit

That way if user1 saved the file at 09:00 and deleted it at 11:00, none of the records would count.  The deleted record isn't included in the results (because of `t.action_type = 'SAVED'`), but it is newer than the 09:00 record so stops that showing.

Answer (score 0):

Since ***'most recently'*** has not proper definition query can be:

```
select count(*) from tlbName where filename='index.html' and action='saved'
```

**If time is there then:**

```
select count(*) from tlbName where filename='index.html' and action='saved' and timestamp between 'timeval_1' and 'timeval_2'
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: there is a time column that I forgot about

Comment: but you have to specify it, most recently means upto what time span 1 hour, 2 hours , 2minutes??

Comment: it's not time based. I just want the lastest one (whenever I run the statement)